# To create random first and last name. multiple pieces

Tags: php, mysql, random, twig, opencart

I want to create a script. The script will automatically list random firstname and lastname.
There are two database tables.

First: fake_name_id, fake_firstname

Second:fake_name_id,fake_lastname

So far I have made this:

controller file

```
$data['lastname'] = array();

$results = $this->getRandomLastNames();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $data['lastname'][] = array(
            'lastname'        => $result['lastname'],
        );
    }

$data['fullnames'] = array();
$results = $this->getRandomNames();

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $data['fullnames'][] = array(
            'firstname'        => $result['firstname'],

        );
    }
```

model file >>>>> sql query firstname and lastname

```
public function getRandomName($fake_name_id) {
                
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, fake_firstname FROM " . DB_PREFIX . " fakereviews_name WHERE fake_name_id = '" . (int)$fake_name_id . "'");
        
        if ($query->num_rows) {
            return array(
                'fake_name_id'             => $query->row['fake_name_id'],
                'firstname'             => $query->row['fake_firstname'],
            );
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public function getRandomNames($data = array()) {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "fakereviews_name ORDER BY Rand() ASC LIMIT 0, 20";
            $fake_firstname_data = array(); 
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                       
            foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
                
                $fake_firstname_data[$result['fake_name_id']] = $this->getRandomName($result['fake_name_id']);
            }       
        return $fake_firstname_data;
    }   
    
    
    
    
 public function getRandomLastName($fake_name_id) {
                
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, fake_lastname FROM " . DB_PREFIX . " fakereviews_lastname WHERE fake_name_id = '" . (int)$fake_name_id . "'");

        if ($query->num_rows) {
            return array(
                'fake_name_id'             => $query->row['fake_name_id'],
                'lastname'             => $query->row['fake_lastname'],
            );
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
        
    public function getRandomLastNames($data = array()) {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "fakereviews_lastname ORDER BY Rand() ASC LIMIT 0, 20";
            
            $fake_lastname_data = array();  
            
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                       
            foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
                
                $fake_lastname_data[$result['fake_name_id']] = $this->getRandomLastName($result['fake_name_id']);
            }       
        return $fake_lastname_data;
    }
```

twig file

```
{% for fullname in fullnames %}
{{ fullname['firstname'] }} {{ fullname['lastname'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

When the page loads. well creates 20 pieces of firstname.

But I can't get it to display lastname correctly.

Please help me to create foreach random fullname (first and last name) with predefined quantity.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `rand()` function.

Create an array of `fake_firstname` and one for `fake_lastname` and then join them using a loop, wrap everything inside a function and you have what you need.

say you need an array of `$n` fake names

Example pseudocode:

```
public function randomNames($n){
    // $first_name_array = fetch all first names in an array;
    // $last_name_array = fetch all last names in an array;
    
    $random_names = [];

    foreach($n as $i){
          $random_full_name = $first_name_array[rand(0,$n)%count($first_name_array)].' '.$last_name_array[rand(0,$n)%count($last_name_array)];
          array_push($random_names,$random_full_name);
    }

    return($random_names);

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do it. :S 
For some reason I can't. :s

Comment: How fetch all array?